# Make it more obvious how to exit the Ask Question Wizard

Tags: feature-request, asking-questions, ask-question-wizard-2018

When asking a new question I noticed that there was a link (no explanation) beneath the heading 'Ask a new question'. It read 'Use guided mode'. So I clicked on it. It opens a new page where you are guided through different steps to ask your question. It looks like it is very helpful for beginners, so I'm pleased.

However, I know how to ask question on Stack Overflow so I wanted to change back to the regular view - but I couldn't find how. This is quite frustrating. Clearing cookies didn't seem to solve the issue so this seems to be a server-side setting. I couldn't find a relevant option in the site settings either.

I finally found that you have to click through the first question in the helper to get the option to return to the traditional mode.

First step (no option to go back)
[image: first step]

Second step (option to go to 'traditional mode')
[image: second step]

**I think it's better to *always* show this option, or at least also show it in the first step.**

Comment: Why is pressing the back button in your browser not sufficient to "go back" to the original ask question page?

Comment: Hm, not sure why but when I first visited this new page I could click forward on the steps, i.e. I could click on 'Description' even if I hadn't filled out the other steps yet. And then going back didn't work. Currently, this is not the case and I can indeed just go back to the traditional mode. However, I still don't think a button is more user-friendly.

Comment: @Servy As a side note: when going back, the URL has changed to include a hash `#` which doesn't look nice. If need be, I can make a separate issue for that.

Comment: I'm old fashioned. I just clicked the stackoverflow logo and hit the ask question button - presto, that returned it back to normal. I don't really see this as much of a problem, you are simply never going to switch to the wizard style again so you won't have to be bothered by the traditional mode link being hidden on the second step. I think for actually new people who get the wizard by design, this is a good thing.

Comment: @Gimby It seems something has already changed in the persistence of the choice you make. When this option first appeared, I couldn't get it back to normal in any way. Going back to the home page, logging out, and even removing cookies or switching browsers did not help: every time I pressed 'Ask question', I got the guided mode. The only way to switch back was to complete the first step, and in the second choose 'Use traditional mode'.

Comment: It should ALWAYS even on step 1 show that link.  It should not hide it.  +1.  You could even make a tooltip that states "Don't need guidance, click back to go to the traditional mode of asking questions...".

Comment: Why making it obvious to exit a prompt which you can exit at the first place by doing some steps will help?

Answer (score -8):

While I appreciate your frustration as an experienced user, we don't want it to be easy for new users to do this. So if it's difficult to get out of guided mode before you've followed at least some of the prompts, to be honest I think that's working as intended! Sorry!

Comment: But also you can't force them to use one method, again nobody is forcing them to, they can exit the prompt anyway.

Comment: Making experiensed users frustrated is not a good idea. There must be better solution.

Comment: @Sanyash E.g. hide it in first step only for new users, with reputation < 50 or are asking their first questions. This will frustrate only multiple-account/coming back users.

Comment: I like @R2RT 's idea of making this dependent on the reputation of users.