# "Post Your question" greyed out

Tags: support

This is in fact identical to this question which says fixed and wont happen again. It is happening again...

[Can't post a new question using guided mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386581/cant-post-a-new-question-using-guided-mode)

However, I cannot comment there and it did not seem appropriate to answer. What gives???

Comment: I commented on there for you linking to this question. I'm not sure if this is supposed to be closed as a dupe, but SE really needs to fix this

Comment: In the meanwhile though, back up your question and (assuming you can, I'm not sure if low-rep users can use traditional mode), [use traditional mode](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382996/6296561).

Comment: There is a workaround posted in one of the comments [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/386581/cant-post-a-new-question-using-guided-mode#comment708684_386629): "The issue is still, my colleague today couldn't post his question, the button was disabled. He has to navigate to one of previous step and then back to last, then button become enabled and he could click it." Does that work for you?

Comment: Thanks.. missed it. Button is no longer greyed out after the workaround. Now I get "Can only post every 90 mins", since I posted this less than 90 mins ago..Hopefully in 90mins it will work.